# PHP inserting multiple checkbox AND textbox arrays into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with the array results in my php. My first problem is this :

[image]

It shows everything even if the checkbox isn't checked. My second problem is that it won't insert the values to the database even though it's connected to the database (as you can see in the previous screenshot, it says "connected successfully").

This is my html form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="cupcake">
    <input type="text" name="items" value="cupcake" readonly><br>
    <b>Price :</b> <span name="price" value="3.00">$17.00</span><br>
    Quantity: <input tabindex="1" name="quantity[]" min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" value="1" /><br>
    <input tabindex="1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="17" /><span>Add to Cart</span></label></div></div></td><br>

    <input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="cake">
    <input type="text" name="items" value="cake" readonly><br>
    <b>Price :</b> <span name="price" value="20.00">$20.00</span><br>
    Quantity: <input tabindex="1" name="quantity[]" min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" value="1" /><br>
    <input tabindex="1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="20" /><span>Add to Cart</span></label></div></div></td><br>

    <input type="submit" name="insertBT"><br>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['insertBT']))
{
    class db_conn
    {
        public function create_conn($servername, $username, $password, $db)
        {
            global $conn;
            $conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $db);
        }

        public function check_conn()
        {
            global $conn;
            if($conn->connect_error)
            {
                die ("Connection Failed : " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            else
            {
                echo ("Connected Successfully <br>");
            }
        }

        public function insert()
        {

            if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
                foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check) {

                    $check = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']);
                    $name = implode(',', $_POST['item']);
                    $quantity = implode(',', $_POST['quantity']);
                }
                echo $check . "<br>";
                echo $name . "<br>";
                echo $quantity . "<br>";

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchases(Product, Quantity, Price) VALUES('$name', '$quantity','$check')");

            }
        }
    }
    $obj1 = new db_conn;
    $obj1->create_conn("localhost","root","", "dbtest");
    $obj1->check_conn();
    $obj1->insert();
}
```

Comment: Pardon me but I'm not asking on how to connect the php file to the database, I already know how to connect it using object oriented programming. I'm asking an entirely different question.

Comment: Why are you using a global variable `$conn` instead of a class property?

Comment: Since you're looping over the checkboxes, why are you also doing `implode(',', $_POST['checkbox'])` inside the loop?

Comment: I'm using implode because I keep getting a notice when I run the page without it. Saying something like "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `implode`. That puts a comma-separated list of everything in the form into each row that you insert, and repeats this for every box that's checked. You should just insert one item in each row, by indexing the arrays.

However, when you have a checkbox in a form, it only submits the ones that are checked. The result of this is that the indexes of the `$_POST['checkbox']` array won't match up with the corresponding `$_POST['item']` and `$_POST['quantity']` elements. You need to put explicit indexes into the `checkbox` names so you can relate them.

```
<form method = "POST">

<input type = "hidden" name = "item[]" value = "cupcake">
<input type = "text" name = "items" value = "cupcake" readonly><br>
<b>Price :</b> <span name = "price" value = "3.00">$17.00</span><br>
Quantity: <input tabindex="1" name="quantity[]" min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" value="1" /><br>
<input tabindex="1" name="checkbox[0]" type="checkbox" value="17" /><span>Add to Cart</span></label></div></div></td><br>

<input type = "hidden" name = "item[]" value = "cake">
<input type = "text" name = "items" value = "cake" readonly><br>
<b>Price :</b> <span name = "price" value = "20.00">$20.00</span><br>
Quantity: <input tabindex="1" name="quantity[]" min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" value="1" /><br>
<input tabindex="1" name="checkbox[1]" type="checkbox" value="20" /><span>Add to Cart</span></label></div></div></td><br>

<input type = "submit" name = "insertBT"><br>
</form>
```

Then your PHP code can be like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO purchases (Product, Quantity, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sis", $name, $quantity, $price);
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $i => $price) {
    $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

BTW, putting the prices in your HTML seems like a bad idea. Nothing stops the user from modifying HTML using the web inspector before they submit the form, so they could lower the price. You should get the prices from the database when processing the form.

Also, notice that in your original code you opened the database connection using MySQLi, but then you tried to do the insert using `mysql_query` instead of `$conn->query()`. You can't mix APIs like that; `myql_query` can only be used when you open the connection with `mysql_connect`.

Comment: and the problem with their original query was? oh yeah,  I mentioned that but was quickly told (more like dismissed) that that wasn't what the question was about, mixing MySQL APIs. so I ended up deleting my comment about it.

Comment: Ahhh I see, so that was the problem. Seems like Fred was right. It's working now, thank you. Also, I don't know what prepare() is but I'm guessing it's just a ready query when the form is sent. But may I ask what the "sis" is for?